# Check a checkBox in a listView .net maui

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

In my project maui i want a helper to check checkBox when I select an item from the listView with multiple selection.
My listView in xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="listViewComande"                  
           ItemSelected="listViewArticle_ItemSelected">
     <ListView.Header >        
     </ListView.Header>
     <ListView.ItemTemplate  >
         <DataTemplate >
             <ViewCell   >
                 <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" 
                       ColumnDefinitions="5*,20*,45*,10*,10*,10*" 
                       Padding="3,10,3,10"  ColumnSpacing="8">
                       <CheckBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" 
                       Color="LightGray"                     
                       x:Name="chekBoxListView" />                  
                     <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Text="{Binding DesignationComande}"      FontSize="13" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
                          HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" MaxLines="1"  FontAttributes="None"/>                  
                 </Grid>
             </ViewCell>
         </DataTemplate>
     </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>

public class ComandeTable
 {
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
     public int ID { get; set; }
     public string ReferenceComande { get; set; }   
     public string DesignationComande { get; set; } 
 }

private void listViewArticle_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{   
    if (e.SelectedItem != null)
    {       
    }
}
```

I used a bool variable but it doesn't work

Comment: What you are trying to achieve is a bit unclear from your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xaml demonstrates an intent to display the `DesignationComande` property and respond when the check box changes (either programmatically or though user interaction). This will require a model for the items in your `ListView` bound to those properties.

For example:

[image: responding to checks]

---

**Finish the bindings in xaml**

Bind the `IsChecked` property in your `DataTemplate`

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="checked_list_view.MainPage">
    <Grid
        RowDefinitions="*,*" >
        <ListView
            Grid.Row="0"
            x:Name="listViewComande"                  
            BackgroundColor="Azure">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate >
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid 
                            RowDefinitions="Auto" 
                            ColumnDefinitions="Auto,20*,45*,10*,10*,10*" 
                            Padding="3,10,3,10" 
                            ColumnSpacing="8">
                            <CheckBox 
                                IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"
                                Grid.Row="1" 
                                Grid.Column="0" 
                                Color="CornflowerBlue" />
                            <Label 
                                Grid.Row="1" 
                                Grid.Column="2"  
                                BackgroundColor="LightGreen"
                                Text="{Binding DesignationComande}"      
                                FontSize="13" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"                            
                                HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" MaxLines="1"  
                                HorizontalOptions="Fill"
                                FontAttributes="None"
                                Padding="10,0"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
        <Editor 
            Grid.Row="1"
            Text="{Binding EditorText}"/>
    </Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

---

**Make a Model for items in the `ListView`**

This functionality requires a bindable property for `IsChecked` that fires a `PropertyChanged` event for the check boxes.

```
class CheckableCommand : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string DesignationComande { get; set; }
    public override string ToString() => DesignationComande;

    public bool IsChecked
    {
        get => _isChecked;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_isChecked, value))
            {
                _isChecked = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    bool _isChecked = false;
    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName]string caller = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(caller));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

---

**Glue it all together**

In this sample, the code-behind for the MainPage sets the `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` (you could also do this in xaml) to an observable collection of `CheckableCommand` and subscribes to the `PropertyChanged` notification of the items.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        BindingContext = this;
        InitializeComponent();
        listViewComande.ItemsSource = new ObservableCollection<CheckableCommand>
        {
            new CheckableCommand{ DesignationComande = "Command 1" },
            new CheckableCommand{ DesignationComande = "Command 2" },
            new CheckableCommand{ DesignationComande = "Command 3" },
        };
        foreach (CheckableCommand command in listViewComande.ItemsSource)
        {
            command.PropertyChanged += (sender, e) =>
            {
                switch (e.PropertyName) 
                {
                    case nameof(CheckableCommand.IsChecked):
                        var checkedCommands = 
                            listViewComande
                            .ItemsSource
                            .OfType<CheckableCommand>()
                            .Where (_ => _.IsChecked)
                            .ToList();
                        if(checkedCommands.Any())
                        {
                            EditorText = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, checkedCommands);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            EditorText = "No checked commands at this time.";
                        }
                        break;
                }
            };            
            listViewComande.ItemSelected += (sender, e) =>
            {
                // Option to check the checkbox when item is selected.
                if (e.SelectedItem is CheckableCommand cmd) cmd.IsChecked = true;
            };
        }
        EditorText = "Hello, I'll be keeping track of your checked commands.";
    }
    public string EditorText
    {
        get => _editorText;
        set
        {
            if (!Equals(_editorText, value))
            {
                _editorText = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
    string _editorText = string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: think you for help  , the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

What I understood, you want to check a `Checkbox` when you select an item in the `listView`. This is how you can do it

```
private void ListView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
{
    var viewCell = ((ListView)sender);
    var checkbox = viewCell.GetVisualTreeDescendants().Where(x => x.GetType() == typeof(CheckBox));
    var currentCheckbox = (CheckBox)checkbox.ElementAt(e.ItemIndex);
    //var currentCheckbox = (CheckBox)checkbox.ToList()[e.ItemIndex];
    if (!currentCheckbox.IsChecked)
        currentCheckbox.IsChecked = true;
    else
        currentCheckbox.IsChecked = false;
}
```

Note one thing, here `ListView_ItemTapped` is `ItemTapped` not `ItemSelected`.

Comment: think you for help , the problem is solved

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating two view models:

- CheckedViewModel - for each item in the collection
- MainViewModel - a parent view model that holds the ObservableCollection and the dynamic list of the selected items

We can subscribe to the `CheckedViewModel.OnPropertyChanged` for each item to the parent `MainViewModel` so that the parent view model gets notified whenever the `IsChecked` changes and it will recompute the `SelectedItems` on demand.

In `MainPage.xaml.cs` we implement `ListView_ItemTapped` to manipulate the collection view model.

```cs
// MauiProgram.cs
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<MainPage>();
```

```cs
// CheckedViewModel.cs
public partial class CheckedViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private bool _isChecked = false;

    [ObservableProperty]
    private string _commandText = string.Empty;
}
```

```cs
// MainViewModel.cs
public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private ObservableCollection<CheckedViewModel> _checkedItems = new()
    {
        new CheckedViewModel { CommandText = "Command 1" },
        new CheckedViewModel { CommandText = "Command 2" },
        new CheckedViewModel { CommandText = "Command 3" },
    };

    public List<CheckedViewModel> SelectedItems => CheckedItems.Where(x => x.IsChecked).ToList();

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        foreach (var item in CheckedItems)
        {
            item.PropertyChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                if (e.PropertyName == nameof(CheckedViewModel.IsChecked))
                {
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedItems));
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

```xml
<!-- MainPage.xaml -->
<VerticalStackLayout x:DataType="{x:Type local:MainViewModel}">
    <ListView x:Name="myView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CheckedItems}"
              ItemTapped="myView_ItemTapped">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type local:CheckedViewModel}">
                <ViewCell>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <Label Text="{Binding CommandText}" />
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
    <Label Text="{Binding SelectedItems.Count, StringFormat='{0} commands checked'}" />
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItems}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="{x:Type local:CheckedViewModel}">
                <ViewCell>
                    <Label Text="{Binding CommandText}" />
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</VerticalStackLayout>
```

```cs
// MainPage.xaml.cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    MainViewModel VM;

    public MainPage(MainViewModel VM)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.VM = VM;
        BindingContext = VM;
    }

    private void myView_ItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
    {
        VM.CheckedItems[e.ItemIndex].IsChecked = !VM.CheckedItems[e.ItemIndex].IsChecked;
    }
}
```